# how to access getFilesDir() as an environment variable?

Tags: java, android, storage

I want to access `getFilesDir()` which is a context method.

Is there any way to access it similarly to the way I access external-storage?

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`

meaning as an environment variable?

Maybe application static context? as I want to call this from a non-context class (same app service, but not an activity).

Comment: Service is also a Context as Service extends Context. so you can call `getFilesDir()` in Service...

Comment: is there a way to get this without context and without passing context?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not possible.

`Context.getFilesDir()` returns a path that is bound to your package and the `Context` is required to access the package name.

`Environment` is different as there's only constants that are common to all apps running on the same runtime.

However, a `Context` is available practically everywhere in an Android application so this shouldn't really be a problem.

---

Follow up:

> how about `Environment.getDataDirectory()`? how can I get `data\data` as from `data\data\com.Myapp` using EnvironmentVar?

`Environment.getDataDirectory()` just returns the part of the data directory common to all apps. For example, the `/data/data`.

To get your own files dir (`getFilesDir()`), your package name and `"/files"` need to be appended to it. `Context` implementation does this for you.

Comment: how can i get `data\data` as from `data\data\com.Myapp` using EnvironmentVar?

Answer (score 15):

There is an excellent documentation on this done by a Githib user, which is really valuable. Maybe it will help someone:

https://gist.github.com/granoeste/5574148

Here is the entire contents posted from the documentation:

[image]

[image]

Comment: wonderful, just what I needed, I understood 100x more than reading the android docs. im staring this